# Error when Generating Barcodes Using barcode Library in PyInstaller Executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, barcode

I have a Python application that uses the `barcode` library to generate barcodes and save them as PNG images. The application works perfectly when run from the Python interpreter, but I encounter an error when I create an executable using PyInstaller and try to run it.

The error I'm encountering is as follows:

```
File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
File "Bachmaier.py", line 668, in save_selection
File "Barcode_generator.py", line 13, in generate_barcodes
  barcode_image = code128.render(writer_options={"font_size": 1, "text_distance": 1})
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "barcode/codex.py", line 255, in render
File "barcode/base.py", line 100, in render
File "barcode/writer.py", line 269, in render
File "barcode/writer.py", line 440, in _paint_text
File "PIL/ImageFont.py", line 791, in truetype
File "PIL/ImageFont.py", line 788, in freetype
File "PIL/ImageFont.py", line 226, in __init__
OSError: cannot open resource
```

Here's the relevant code snippet where the error occurs:

```py
import os
from barcode import Code128
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

def generate_barcodes(stl_names, path):
    barcodes = []  # To store the barcode image paths
    
    for name in stl_names:
        barcode_name = f"{name}"
        code128 = Code128(barcode_name, writer=ImageWriter())

        # Generate the barcode as a PIL image
        barcode_image = code128.render(writer_options={"font_size": 1, "text_distance": 1})

        # Save the barcode image as a PNG file
        barcode_file_path = os.path.join(path, f"{barcode_name}.png")
        barcode_image.save(barcode_file_path, "PNG")

        barcodes.append(barcode_file_path)
    return barcodes
```

The error seems to be related to accessing a resource, but I'm not explicitly using any fonts in my code. The issue appears only when I run the executable generated by PyInstaller; running the script directly in the Python interpreter works fine.

I've tried including the `--add-data` flag with PyInstaller to ensure resources are packaged, but the issue persists. What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it? Is there anything specific I need to consider when working with the `barcode` library in a PyInstaller executable?

Any insights or guidance on troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting an error using the barcode module. Instead I used the win32 module and 'wrote' the barcode with the code 3 of 9 barcode font. See example below

```
import win32print
import win32ui
import win32con

Barcode = 123456

printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
hprinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
printer_info = win32print.GetPrinter(hprinter, 2)

printer_dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
printer_dc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)

printer_dc.StartDoc('My Document')
printer_dc.StartPage()

# change font to Barcode Font
# Set barcode font attributes
barcode_font = win32ui.CreateFont({
    'name': '3 of 9 Barcode',  # Replace with your installed barcode font name
    'height': 72,  # Adjust the font height as needed
    'weight': 400,  # Adjust the font weight as needed
})
printer_dc.SelectObject(barcode_font)
# write barcode
printer_dc.TextOut(40, 200, f'*{Barcode}*') #since my barcode contains only numbers I have to put the *'s around it otherwise the barcode won't display the right number 40, 200 is the position on the page where i printed the barcode

printer_dc.EndPage()
printer_dc.EndDoc()
printer_dc.DeleteDC()
```

Answer (score 0):

`barcode.writer` comes from the `python-barcode` module. You don't have that installed in your system, hence the error.

So, do `pip install python-barcode`. then replace `from barcode import Code128` with `from barcode.codex import Code128`. As it seems, the developers upgraded the library and you can no longer import the codex directly from barcode class.

So, all in all your code should look like below:

```
import os
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from barcode.codex import Code128

def generate_barcodes(stl_names, path):
    barcodes = []  # To store the barcode image paths
    
    for name in stl_names:
        barcode_name = f"{name}"
        code128 = Code128(barcode_name, writer=ImageWriter())

        # Generate the barcode as a PIL image
        barcode_image = code128.render(writer_options={"font_size": 1, "text_distance": 1})

        # Save the barcode image as a PNG file
        barcode_file_path = os.path.join(path, f"{barcode_name}.png")
        barcode_image.save(barcode_file_path, "PNG")

        barcodes.append(barcode_file_path)
    return barcodes
```

Comment: Sorry. I do have barcode
Requirement already satisfied: python-barcode in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (0.15.1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have modified the answer. I checked the script on my side too, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the help! However, it's still not working. I also attempted to use the 'treepoem' library, but that didn't work either. It seems like when I'm trying to create an executable file with PyInstaller, the libraries are not being saved properly.